# Difficulties selecting a moving gameobject

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine, physics

I am developing a mobile game with touch controls. I can select a non-moving gameobject very easily and it responds, however it's very difficult to select it when it's moving since it's kind of small (falling for example, it's all physics based). Is there a way to increase the touch radius of the gameobject so that it can be pressed more easily, or is there another solution?

```
 private void Update() {
    //User input (touches) will select cubes
    if(Input.touchCount > 0) {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    }
    Touch[] touches = Input.touches;

    foreach(var touchInput in touches) {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint((Input.GetTouch(0).position)), Vector2.zero);

        if (hit.collider != null) {
            selectedCube = hit.collider.gameObject;
            selectedCube.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color32.Lerp(defaultColor, darkerColor, 1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: well i don't know how many Gameobjects are in the scene at one time but what about increasing Collider size?

Comment: @AmRzA If I increase the Collider size the objects above this one are going to float in the air

Comment: and what about using a while(true) inside of a coroutine?

Comment: @AmRzA How is a loop going to fix the problem?

Comment: because probably it is faster than update.actually i think it's fastest way possible.

Comment: @AmRzA Where did you get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than increasing the object's collider size (which you discussed in the comments), how about approaching this the opposite way? Check in an area around the touch for a collision, instead of just the single point, using [`Physics2D.CircleCast`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.CircleCast.html):

```
private void Update() {
    //User input (touches) will select cubes
    if(Input.touchCount > 0) {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    }
    Touch[] touches = Input.touches;

    foreach(var touchInput in touches) {
        float radius = 1.0f; // Change as needed based on testing
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.CircleCast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint((Input.GetTouch(0).position)), radius, Vector2.zero);

        if (hit.collider != null) {
            selectedCube = hit.collider.gameObject;
            selectedCube.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color32.Lerp(defaultColor, darkerColor, 1);
        }

    }
}
```

Note that this won't be great if you've got tons of selectable objects flush against each other...but then again, increasing collider size in that case wouldn't help either. (I'd say just increase object size. No way to otherwise improve user accuracy. Or allow multi-select, and use [`Physics2D.CircleCastAll`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.CircleCastAll.html)).

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT:** For better accuracy, since the "first" result returned by `Physics2D.CircleCast` may be arbitrarily selected, you can instead use `Physics2D.CircleCastAll` to get all objects within the touch radius, and only select the one which is closest to the original touch point:

```
private void Update() {
    //User input (touches) will select cubes
    if(Input.touchCount > 0) {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    }
    Touch[] touches = Input.touches;

    foreach(var touchInput in touches) {
        float radius = 1.0f; // Change as needed based on testing
        Vector2 worldTouchPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        RaycastHit2D[] allHits = Physics2D.CircleCastAll(worldTouchPoint, radius, Vector2.zero);

        // Find closest collider that was hit
        float closestDist = Mathf.Infinity;
        GameObject closestObject = null;
        foreach (RaycastHit2D hit in allHits){

            // Record the object if it's the first one we check,
            // or is closer to the touch point than the previous
            if (closestObject == null ||
                Vector2.Distance(closestObject.transform.position, worldTouchPoint) < closestDist){
                closestObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
                closestDist = Vector2.Distance(closestObject.transform.position, worldTouchPoint);
            }
        }

        // Finally, select the object we chose based on the criteria
        if (closestObject != null) {
            selectedCube = closestObject;
            selectedCube.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color32.Lerp(defaultColor, darkerColor, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, however when there is an object near that one it selects it instead. If I lower the radius it doesn't happen as often but it happens nontheless, which is bad. There's an Android game called QuadRush that also has the same type of falling gameobjects (2d squares) and with almost the same size as mine, yet it's very easy to select them. Could you maybe take a look at it?

Comment: I suspect QuadRush is benefited by the fact that it involves matching of shapes which share an attribute (indicated by their colour). Perhaps it records the colour of the first shape chosen - that way, if a subsequent tap or swipe technically selects multiple shapes, then it can choose only the one(s) that share the original colour. (Also note that most of the actions demonstrated in the QuadRush video are on stationary shapes. Fast-moving small shapes will always be hard to tap with something as inaccurate as a fingertip.)

Comment: One way that may (potentially) improve accuracy with the circle touch approach is to use `Physics2D.CircleCastAll` instead, iterate through each of the hit objects, and only select the one that is closest to the original touch point. Let me know if you need me to edit that into the answer.

Comment: Since I'm new to Unity, please do! Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Milen All done - let me know how my new edit works out. Unfortunately, I can't really try out my code since I don't have Unity around at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, it works great. All I did was lower the radius from 1 to 0.1